# React native app not receiving notifications via TOPIC in Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have configured the react-native to the best of my knowledge
using some documentations. The react native app receives notifications properly when selecting the whole app as the target.But I am not able to get the same when sending via topics from the firebase console. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Screen shot of receiving notification via app as target.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8huVS.png

**Code**

PushNotifHelper

```
    import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

    const TOPIC = 'patient-topic';

    export const requestUserPermission = async () => {
      //On ios,checking permission before sending and receiving messages
      const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
      return (
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
        authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL
      );
    };

    export const getFcmToken = () => {
      // Returns an FCM token for this device
      messaging()
        .getToken()
        .then(fcmToken => {
          console.log('FCM Token -> ', fcmToken);
        });
    };

    export const receiveNotificationFromQuitState = () => {
      messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(async remoteMessage => {
          if (remoteMessage) {
            console.log(
              'getInitialNotification:' +
                'Notification caused app to open from quit state',
            );
          }
        });
    };

    export const receiveBackgroundNotification = () => {
      messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'onNotificationOpenedApp: ' +
              'Notification caused app to open from background state',
          );
        }
      });
    };

    //stop listening for new messages.
    export const unsubscribeDeviceTopic = messaging().onMessage(
      async remoteMessage => {
        console.log('New notification arrived' + JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
      },
    );

    export const backgroundThread = () => {
      //It's called when the app is in the background or terminated
      messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
        console.log('Background notification' + JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
      });
    };

    export const subscribeTopicToGetNotification = () => {
      /**
       * based on Topic, FCM server to send targeted
       * messages to only those devices subscribed to that topic
       */
      messaging()
        .subscribeToTopic(TOPIC)
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Topic: ${TOPIC} Suscribed`);
        });
    };
```

Initialising inside useEffect

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function setupPatientNotification() {
          if (await requestUserPermission()) {
            getFcmToken();
          } else {
            console.log('Not Authorization status');
          }
        }
        receiveNotificationFromQuitState();
        receiveBackgroundNotification();
        subscribeTopicToGetNotification();
        backgroundThread();
        return () => {
          unsubscribeDeviceTopic;
          // messaging().unsubscribeFromTopic(TOPIC);
        };
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on my side because I have a separate subscribed topic without waiting to retrieve a token from Firebase.

I think you need to move to subscribe topic after the system gets Fcm Token or after authorization notification permission.

This is an example of my code, now it works properly.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await createChannelId();
      const authorizationStatus = await requestUserPermission();
      await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
      if (authorizationStatus) {
        const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
        setItem(FCM_TOKEN, fcmToken);
        subscribeTopic(NotificationTopics.ApplicationUpdate);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```